# Deployment of DB TFS MSBuild

Tags: database, deployment, tfs

I have the following problem deploying our ASP.net Webproject. The Deployment just runs fine. I'm using TFS 2010 and deploy the application through the msbuild arguments (/p:DeployOnBuild=True etc.).

The problem I'm running into is the deployment of our database. At the moment I'm trying to use the Package/Publish SQL settings of the web project. The connection string for the destination database looks as follows

Data Source=SomeIP, 1433; Initial Catalog=MYDatabase; User ID=DeploymentUser; Password=PW;

So I'm trying to use an sql login to login to the sql server (sql server 2012, the respective user is dbowner) but every db deployment fails because msbuild always tries to login to the sql server with the buildservice account.

One solution might be to grant access to the sql server of the build account. Unfortunately this is not possible for us because the dbserver is not in our domain.

Any ideas how i can force msbuild using the sql login specified in the connection string?

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing any of this:

"Import from Web.config
Finds connection strings in the Web.config file and enters their names into the Database Entries grid with "-Deployment" appended to them.
You can change the "-Deployment" suffix to "-Web.config" (for example, change "ConnectionStringName-Deployment" to "ConnectionStringName-Web.config") in order to specify that the connection string value in the Web.config file should be used for deployment. For more information, see Connection string for destination database later in this document."

and is it taking the connection string from your web.config?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576376.aspx